# Swift NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key Not Reading

Tags: ios, swift

I have added the key and string message to the .plist but for some reason my app keeps crashing and I dont know why. I added to the .plist file from swift and i also tried adding it manually to the code. Its not working when i run the app it still crashes when i get to that point.

https://useyourloaf.com/assets/images/2016/2016-07-03-001.png

Error Message:

```
This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data 
without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an  
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a 
string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.




import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import KeychainSwift


class UserProfile: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    //Username UI Label
    @IBOutlet weak var changeImageButton: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userProfileImage: UIImageView!

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var storage: FIRStorageReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
         storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

        //Make Porfile Image Cirlce
        userProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = userProfileImage.frame.size.width/2
        userProfileImage.clipsToBounds = true

        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        ref.child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            let username = snapDict?["Username"] as? String ?? "" //Get Username


            //print("Username: " + username)

            self.usernameLabel.text = username //Label set to UserName


        })

    }//View Did load


    @IBAction func choosePicture(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Picture", message: "Choose From", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
            pickerController.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


        let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default) { (action) in
            pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

        let savedPhotosAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Saved Photos Album", style: .default) { (action) in
            pickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
            self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
        alertController.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
        alertController.addAction(savedPhotosAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }//END CHOOSE PICTURE

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPackageImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.userProfileImage.image = image
    }


    func updateProfilePicture() {

        //Assign current user ID
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        //Create an access point for the Firebase Storage
        let storageItem = storage.child("profile_images").child(userID!)

        guard let image = userProfileImage.image else {return}

        if let newImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {

            //upload to Firebase
            storageItem.put(newImage, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil{
                print(error!)
                return

            }

                storageItem.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                    return
                    }
        })
    })

}


}


    //UI Button: Sign Out the User
    @IBAction func SignOut(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let firebaseAuth = FIRAuth.auth()
                    do {
                        try firebaseAuth?.signOut()
                    } catch let signOutError as NSError {
                        print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
                    }
                    //KeychainSwift().delete("uid")
                    DataService().keyChain.delete("uid")
                    dismiss(animated: true , completion: nil)
    }








}//End UserProfile Class
```

Comment: Could this be because I am testing on simulator? Is this allowed on the simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong one. Should Be "Privacy Photo Library Usage"

Comment: @MyMasterPeice with latest you meant 10.2? It should work as the API has not changed at all. Be aware that If you are using the camera you need to ask for both Camera "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" and Photo "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" and the value cannot be empty you need to put something.

Comment: i tried both infact i tired few permission also which is not needed but related to media but still it is givving me error saying NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription should be define in info.plist , tried cleaning anf build but somehow xcode is not picking up the permissions very weird but it is not wokring

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` as key and your description in your `info.plist`